# Crossvalidation of polynomial lm in R - error: lengths differ

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation

I found other questions regarding this topic, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350357/cv-glm-variable-lengths-differ), however I am keep getting the error message

> Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :    'x' and 'y' lengths
>   differ

Below is the code I am using:

```
library(DAAG)
attach(ultrasonic)

g.poly = lm(UR ~ poly(MD, 3), data = ultrasonic)
cv.poly <- cv.lm(ultrasonic, g.poly ,m=3, plotit=TRUE, printit=TRUE, dots=FALSE, seed=29)
```

Of course, the length is same:

```
> length(UR)
[1] 214
> length(MD)
[1] 214
```

Note that in the same script, I perform another linear regression with crossvalidation, which works.

```
library(DAAG)
g.lin = lm(log(UR) ~ MD, data = ultrasonic)
cv.lin <- cv.lm(ultrasonic, g.lin ,m=3, plotit=TRUE, printit=TRUE, dots=FALSE, seed=29)
```

Any idea why the polynomial regression crossvalidation does not work?

**EDIT**

To get the data:

```
install.packages('nlsmsn')
library('nlsmsn')
data(Ultrasonic)

#names differ, i am using copy in local machine with lower case u(ultrasonic) and different column names, but data are identical.
#UR = y
#MD = x
```

Comment: First, do not `attach` the data.frame. Then, your error results from plotting. Do you get the same error if you switch off plotting in `cv.lm`? Finally, a reproducible example is needed for further diagnosis.

Comment: I'd be glad to be wrong but there seems to be bugs and badly formatted if else statements in `cv.lm`

Comment: `Ultrasonic` not `ultrasonic` btw?

Comment: @Roland - In the answers I found, they always recommend to attach the dataframe. But it is same when detached. Further, I still get the error when I switch off the plotting.

Comment: You can trust @Roland and burn all books that defend `attach`ing.

Comment: No `UR` or `MD` variables in the `Ultrasonic` dataset ...

Comment: @ZheyuanLi : tried to extract the function and run it manually... quite a nightmare yet I still hope _I_'m the problem

Comment: @roland, sorry, names differ. See the update.

Comment: @Roland ```g.poly = lm(y ~ poly(x, 3), data = ultrasonic);
cv.poly <- cv.lm(ultrasonic, g.poly ,m=3, plotit=TRUE, printit=TRUE, dots=FALSE, seed=29) ```doesnt work either anyway ;-) !

Comment: @HonzaB are you trying to get more than residuals and/or other measure of how well fitted are your points ? in others words, do you have the feeling that `predict` is not enough?

Comment: @VincentBonhomme well all i need is to fit two or three regression models and somehow compare their performance. So i was thinking CV can be good here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DAAG:::cv.lm` obviously does not support everything you can do with `lm`, e.g., it does not support functions in the formula. You need to take an intermediate step.

```
mf <- as.data.frame(model.matrix(y ~ poly(x), data = Ultrasonic))
mf$y <- Ultrasonic$y
mf$`(Intercept)` <- NULL

#sanitize names
names(mf) <- make.names(names(mf))
#[1] "poly.x." "y"  
g.poly.san <- lm(y ~ ., data = mf)

cv.poly <- cv.lm(mf, g.poly.san, m=3, plotit=TRUE, printit=TRUE, dots=FALSE, seed=29) 
#works
```