# cv.glm variable lengths differ despite correct model formula

Tags: r, cross-validation, glm, cv.glm

I am experiencing the same error as raised and answered here ([cv.glm variable lengths differ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350357/cv-glm-variable-lengths-differ/67504911?noredirect=1#comment119316669_67504911)) and in various other threads. Despite using the "correct" formula structure as suggested in all these threads, the error persists:

`mod <- glm(Y ~ Var_1, data = df, family = binomial)`

`cv.glm(df, mod, K=8)`

Error in model.frame.default(formula = Y ~ Var_1, data = list( :
variable lengths differ (found for 'Var1')

Are there any other known sources of this issue?

Comment: can you post an example that reproduces your error or `dput` your data?  Also edit your question to include which `library` do you use.With simulated data, your code work properly

Comment: Thanks. Actually, think I just found the answer whilst preparing my dataset for this post. I will post below

Answer (score 0):

My response variable was actually defined as

`Y <- cbind(df$Y2, df$Y1-Y2)`, and so whilst the model formula looked like it was in the correct format, the way my response variable was created posed an issue.

If I use the alternative of:

`mod <- glm(Y2/Y1 ~ Var1, family = binomial, data = df, weights = Y1)`

then running `boot::cv.glm(df, mod, K = 8)` works.